# How did my device know where I am located even though my GPS was turned off?

Tags: gps, facebook, geolocation, location-services

So I was testing some functionality levels with Facebook Check-In feature on an Android device (Galaxy S2) and I noticed something strange. Even though my GPS was turned off, When I Checked-In on the Facebook App it showed my current location (along with a pop-up asking me to turn on GPS for more accurate reporting).

Why and more importantly how did my device know where I was located with my GPS being turned off?

Comment: Also relevant is [How does Google Maps estimate my location without GPS?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15009)

Answer (score 0):

either through trianglation or through Wifi if you where connected

trianglation - sends ping requests to Access Points

Wifi - In window 8 it can give a location based on surrounding Wifi network althought I am not awear of android using this