# Can I disable GPS?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, gps, permissions, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Is there a way to completely switch off GPS or deny apps access to it?

Even though all three checkboxes in `Settings -> More -> Location Services` are unchecked and the button in the notification drawer is off, apps are still able to determine my location using GPS.

[image: GPS "disabled" and Location set by GPS at the same time]

Disabling the `Access to my location` checkbox is not *completely* without effect, it does prevent Google Maps from showing my location. I noticed that in [this demo application](https://github.com/will-quast/android-location-demo) the "fused" location stops working but the "GPS" location still works. I further noticed that in GrabTaxi, a taxi hailing app, the map is disabled, but it is still able to search for "nearby places" (with much better accuracy than [GeoIP](https://www.maxmind.com/de/locate_my_ip)).

Comment: related: [How can Google Maps accurately locate my phone when GPS is disabled?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21892/how-can-google-maps-accurately-locate-my-phone-when-gps-is-disabled?rq=1)